# How to suppress or kill the "Autodesk Desktop Connector" prompt by the C# code

Tags: c#, autodesk, revit-api

I am getting this prompt while opening the model. But I wanted to suppress it programmatically. So I can able to read the document data at the backend without user interaction.

[image: Autodesk Desktop Connector warning prompt]

I tried to find the inbuilt Revit API support for this, but no luck.

Comment: Have you tried any of these approaches? https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2010/08/suppress-unwanted-dialogue.html